# How the CLR locates pdb symbol files

Tags: c#, .net, clr, symbols

I would like to know how the CLR locates pdb symbol files, and if this behavior can be overridden.

I looked online (MSDN and other resources) but could not find a good answer.

In my app, i have DLLs placed in several subdirectories of the main .EXE path.

I would like to have a Symbols\ dir that will contain all symbols for my application.
By default, i believe that symbols are picked up from where the assembly is. Can this be changed?

Comment: When a managed exception occurs, an Exception object is created and when symbols are available, it contains a stack trace with file information (source file:line number). I believe the CLR (or whoever adds the stack trace to the exception queries these files).

Comment: BTW the CLR may call into other (Win32) code, so it is partly true that in itself it may not know anything about PDB files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply set the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environment variable for your own process.  This worked well:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        path = Path.Combine(path, "symbols");
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("_NT_SYMBOL_PATH", path);
        try {
            Kaboom();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    static void Kaboom() {
        throw new Exception("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Will it work only when debugging or also when i deploy my application elsewhere?

Comment: I tested this without a debugger and running the Release build.  I don't see a good failure mode for this, other than not putting the .pdbs in the right subdirectory of course.

Comment: I am running a DEBUG build, not sure if that matters or not. Setting the environment variable early in the initialization of my app. I've placed all symbols in the correct folder, however it doesn't seem to pick it up from there.

Answer (score 4):

Look at this blog post if you havn't already:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2007/06/21/customizing-pdb-lookup-for-source-information-in-stacktrace.aspx