# My assembly in GAC throws exception how to log source and line number?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have an assembly which in production deployments is installed in the GAC. When an exception is thrown by this assembly, I would like to log the exception with source + line numbers.

- One alternative is to create a minidump and examine later, but this is too
  heavy handed for known non-critical exceptions.
- Another alternative is to run a script to copy the pdbs into the GAC folder.

If the executing process is deployed with all the requisite pdbs (even for GACed assemblies it references), are there any other-lightweight options to enable source + line information with exceptions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How the CLR locates pdb symbol files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835018/how-the-clr-locates-pdb-symbol-files)

Comment: Is copying pdbs into the respective GAC folder considered bad practice? If so, why?

Comment: If you can figure out what folder to copy it to then maybe not.  You are not expected to figure that out.  No cleanup when the assembly is uninstalled doesn't exactly win prizes either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on [this post](http://timrayburn.net/blog/how-to-put-pdbs-in-the-gac/), putting the pdb's in the gac is doable.

Question: Is there anything preventing you from keeping the dll's in the program's directory?

If the dll's aren't shared / are exclusive to this one application, it may be the a cleaner to include the dll's and PDB's in program's dir.

If this is web, you'd just toss the them into bin.
If its a local app, the program directory can host the dll's as well.

Hope this helps!

Update: Just found another option
[Stack Trace via manual symbol lookup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2007/06/21/code-sample-stacktrace-with-manual-symbol-lookup.aspx)

Basically it allows you to store the PDB's outside of the GAC.  You can store them locally (or even remotely if permissions allow) and retrieve the stack trace from in-GAC dll's.

Comment: It happens to be the assemblies of a service I install. During install, the assemblies are GACed. I'm leaning against changing the installer as it is not something I directly own.

Comment: Understandable - If you don't control the installer all of my solutions are basically out the window.  The closest I can get would be to use a first run flag on your program, and copy a "local" set PDB's into the Gac via that blog post I linked to.

Comment: Just found a new suggestion.  See the update section to my original post